# auto div and field in Collection Form Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, twig, formbuilder

i have a collection of form. When i render my result i have div and label for each Form ( when i use prototype for add form, these are also added) 
first form is

```
namespace Webwall\CamBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SocialType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder

                ->add('account')

        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Webwall\CamBundle\Entity\Social',
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'social';
    }

}
```

The "main Form" is

```
namespace Webwall\CamBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MediaType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder                
                ->add('socials', 'collection', array(
                    'type' => new SocialType(),
                    'allow_add' => true, 
                ))

        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Webwall\CamBundle\Entity\Media'
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'foto';
    }

}
```

In my Twig

```
<div id="form_foto">
{{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

in my dom i have this

```
<div><label class="required">Socials</label><div id="foto_socials" data-prototype=""><div><label class="required">0</label>
```

Why i have this div of Default??
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your complete `<div id="form_foto">` in your twig and the one rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit twig file

```
                        <ul class="unstyled child" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.socials.vars.prototype)|e }}">
                            {% for row in form.socials %}
                                <li style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> {{ form_widget(row.account) }}</li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
```

Comment: when i use Prototype for new field i have all structure of form, like label etc...can i personalize the output?

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issue, you can either modify **twig** (as suggested by Kaan) **OR** you can modify your type form as follow just by **adding the options line**:

```
    $builder                
            ->add('socials', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new SocialType(),
                'options' => array('label' => false), // ADD THIS LINE IN YOUR CODE
                'allow_add' => true, 
            ))
```